# Add registry key using function in innosetup

Tags: inno-setup

How can i add a registry key in innosetup with a value from a function. I want to set the
value of IsServer in registry as the return value of InstallAsServer

```
[Code]
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\company\product\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "IsServer"; ValueData: {code:InstallAsServer}

var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  IsServer: Boolean;
procedure InitializeWizard;
 begin
  Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome,
  'Install Type', 'Select Install Type',
  'Please select Installation type; If Server click Server else Client',
  True, False);

  // Add items
  Page.Add('Install as Server');
  Page.Add('Install as Client');

  // Set initial values (optional)
  Page.Values[0] := True;
  Page.Values[1] := False;
  IsServer := Page.Values[0];
end;

function InstallAsServer(emppararm: string): string; //emppararm not used just for syntax
begin
  if (IsServer=False) then
    begin
      result:= '0';
    end
  else
   begin
    result:= '1';
   end

end;
```

But i always get the value set as 1 even if i select server or client in the page

Comment: thanks a bunch it worked.. (closed as answered) btw can i ask another question ? how can i remove license agreement page?

Comment: got it. if i remove license file the page wil not be shown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens because you're assigning the value of your `IsServer` variable only at the wizard form initialization. You'd need to read the actual value ideally from your `InstallAsServer` function, thus you can even remove the `IsServer` variable. You might simplify your code to something like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\company\product\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "IsServer"; ValueData: {code:InstallAsServer}

[Code]
var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, 'Install Type', 'Select Install Type',
    'Please select Installation type; If Server click Server else Client', True, 
    False);

  // add items
  Page.Add('Install as Server');
  Page.Add('Install as Client');

  // set initial values (optional)
  Page.Values[0] := True;
  Page.Values[1] := False;
end;

function InstallAsServer(Value: string): string;
begin
  // read the actual value directly from the Page
  if not Page.Values[0] then
    Result := '0'
  else
    Result := '1';    
end;
```